# Can lb-ng (loopback-sdk-angular-cli) generated angular SDK can be used in IONIC 3 project having Angular 6.x

Tags: ionic3, loopbackjs, angular-loopback

I have LoopBack3 Server project 
I want to use the SDK generated by lb-ng (loopback-sdk-angular-cli) in IONIC 3 project having Angular 6.x.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, the LoopBack AngularJS SDK package is for AngularJS (Angular v1). Checkout the community forked project that may work for your version of Angular: https://github.com/mean-expert-official/loopback-sdk-builder